# Find all divisors of an polynomial (simple combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I want to implement the multivariate Kronecker factorization algorithm and
at one stage I need to find out all divisors of a polynomial $u(y,\dots)$.

I already know the irreducible factorization of $u(y,\dots)$, but I really need to find out every divisor of $u(y,\dots)$: for example, if $u(y) = y(y+1)(y-1)$ then the divisors are: $1$, $y$, $y+1$, $y-1$, $y(y+1)$, $y(y-1)$, $(y-1)(y+1)$, and $u(y)$ itself.

So it's just a matter of arranging the factors to get the divisors.
But how should I arrange them to find all divisors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as with integers: If the irreducible factorization of $u$ is $p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then there are $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$ divisors in total, all of them of the form $p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_k^{b_k}$ with $0\le b_1\le a_1$, ..., $0\le b_k\le a_k$.